# Convert Data Grid View to Report Viewer

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, reportviewer

Gentleman,

I read over 30 search entries (and tried them all), most of which did not have reply's, before I constructed this question.  Although this is the first time I have ever asked a question here, this has been my favorite place to get answers for over 10 years. And so here goes...I created the following code to accept data from my dataset on another page and propagate it in a report viewer.

```
    //Creates the Grid View
        dataGridViewReport.DataSource = null;            
        dataGridViewReport.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        //Creates the Report
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @" \Report1.rdlc";// @"C:\Users\Pat\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TTW 151200\TTW\Report1.rdlc";
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dt.TableName = "DataSet1";
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataGridViewReport.DataSource);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);            
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

When the page loads, this page accepts the dataset value from the constructor and uses it in the code above. This has been an ordeal up until now, but I think this might be close. I think the problem might be that the report file cannot be found, although it is no longer throwing that error. Now, when I created the report file (Report1.rdlc), it appears with the other form files. What I thought I read is that this would then be located, on RUNTIME, in the /bin OR /release folder, but it does not appear to be there, nor can I copy it to that location. I cannot find where the actual path is, only the path while it is not running. So ... first, I am not sure if I have the code correct to create the report but it is no longer throwing any errors. The view display simply says that it cannot locate this file. And second, just where should I be pointing at so that this code (or any code) has the correct path to the file so the report can be created. Finally, I don't understand the arguments that require the dataset name, so I simply copied from some examples that I found of code that supposedly worked.  I changed the Build Action to Embedded Resource and also the Copy the Copy To Output to Copy Always in the properties table (although it never worked for me).  Please help. A simple, clear code snippet would go a long way to helping me regain my sanity! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `ReportPath` as `Application.StartupPath` + `<report name>` (better using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) insted of string concatenation) could be correct once you have installed your application using setup.

But during debug you have to consider that:

- compiled files (`exe`, `dll`, etc.) are in `bin` folder (`bin`, `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`)
- `rdlc` files remain in your original project folder

So you can implement a function that do something like this (sorry VB.NET code):

```
Private Function strRdlcFilePath(ByVal strRdlcFile As String) As String

    If Debugger.IsAttached And IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine("<path to your project folder>", strRdlcFile)) Then
        strRdlcFilePath = IO.Path.Combine("<path to your project folder>", strRdlcFile)
    ElseIf Not Debugger.IsAttached And IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, strRdlcFile)) Then
        strRdlcFilePath = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, strRdlcFile)
    Else
        'worst case: use an OpenFileDialog to manually select your rdlc file
        strRdlcFilePath = "YourOpenFileDialog.FileName"
    End If

End Function
```

In order to set `ReportPath` as:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = strRdlcFilePath("Report1.rdlc")
```

Regarding dataset question I think your code is correct but having previously declared a `DataTable` it's better using:

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);
```